# Hide table row when user clicks inside textbox

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, vb.net

How do I hide a table row when a user clicks in a textbox?

I have tried this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tcodeVar').focusin(function () {
        $('tr.trEventhide').hide();
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>Code:</td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tcodeVar" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="trEventhide" runat="server">
    <td>Event?:</td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLEvent2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Question not clear.. Rephrasing needed..!

Comment: post related html code.

Comment: when a user clicks inside a textbox, hide a table row? As in when a user goes to edit some text in a textbox a table row gets hidden

Comment: from description and sample code it looks good enough, please explain what error you are getting and yes like other said post html related to it.

Comment: thanks for your replies, i have added the HTML, no errors, nothing happens when I click inside the textbox

Comment: Have you used masterpage??

Comment: change `$('tr.trEventhide').hide();` to `$('#trEventhide').hide();` .You need `#` id-selector

Comment: @TusharGupta thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it as I am tryning to learn JQuery!

Comment: @neeko i have posted it as answer and also posted links for you to study .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$("tr.trEventhide").hide();
```

to

```
$("#trEventhide").hide();
```

You need [# id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

---

[Learn jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/)

[API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/)

[Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)